# 1 crossword and 2 connected alphametic (more clues)

Tags: logical-deduction, no-computers, crosswords, alphametic

Rules :

1. Solve the Crossword.
2. The words can be written backward (example zebra -> arbez)
3. After finishing the crossword, solve the alphametics.
4. The crossword is only uses 10 letters.
5. Each letter represents a number (0...9).
6. No leading 0 in the alphametics.
7. A same letter in both alphametics represents a same number.
8. No computer.
9. Have Fun!!

[image: Crossword]

Horizontal:
1.  Irregular or jagged or uneven
9.  Large crucifixes at the entrance to the chancel of a church
17. Sidelong glances / oblique glances

Vertical:
1. gets/receives something as return
3. A silver-alloy coin of France issued during the Middle Ages
5. A town in the state of Nevada (8 Letters, take 5 first letters)

[image: Alphametic]

Note : I have changed the clues to make the puzzle easier

Comment: Should that be "ancient coin*s*" instead of "ancient coin"?

Comment: @sid No, it is singular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crossword:

> [image]

The alphametic:

> [image]

The alphametic solution:

> Given the OOE and EOE columns, we can deduce that O=0 and E=1.
>
>  [image]
>
>  From the first alphametic we can deduce:
>
> 1+S=L
> S+D=11
> 1+R=S
>
> From the second alphametic we can deduce:
>
> A+B>10
> R+1=S
>
> We also know that R≠0, S≠0, and L≠0 because of the ban on leading zeros.

If we allow different letters to correspond to the same number, there are multiple solutions. I thus assume that each letter is supposed to stand for a unique number.

Trying possibilities for S yields contradictions for all except one case:

> S=1, contradiction (no way to satisfy S+D column)
>  S=2, contradiction (R forced to be 1, which is already used)
>  S=3, contradiction (R forced to be 3, which is already used)
>  S=4, contradiction (no way to satisfy N+5=A without repeating a number)
>  S=5, contradiction (L=6 and D=6)
>  **S=6, leads to N=5, A=9, B=7, V=6**
>  S=7, contradiction (N=1, which is already used)
>  S=8, contradiction (no way to satisfy N+L column, which must be <10)
>  S=9, contradiction (L forced to be 0, which is already used)

So the final solution is:

> [image]

Comment: The crossword is correct, now I'm waiting for the alphametic.

Comment: I upvote for the crossword, I will put green tick for the correct alphametic